# i want to create a navigation bar blocks that have different background colors blocks and different hover colors blocks

Tags: html, css

I want to create a navigation bar blocks that have different background colors blocks and different hover colors blocks . I can create different hover colors blocks or different background colors blocks separately but cannot create It together . so please tell me how to add both together in li class.

The below code is for creating navigation bar

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #373948;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Meddon', cursive;
}

header nav ul {
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li {
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a {
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  padding: 17px 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 3px solid #373948;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #373948;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: color 1s ease;
  -o-transition: color 1s ease;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

The below code is for different hover background-colors for different links.please add changes this may be  wrong.

```css
header nav ul li #link1 a:hover{
  background-color: #373948;
}

header nav ul li #link2 a:hover{
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

header nav ul li #link3 a:hover{
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

header nav ul li #link4 a:hover{
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

The below code is for different background-colors for different links.

```css
header nav ul li a.link-1 { background-color: #00c0e4; }
header nav ul li a.link-2 { background-color: #e6567a; }
header nav ul li a.link-3 { background-color: #eac14d; }
header nav ul li a.link-4 { background-color: #5bd999; }
```

now please tell me that how to add both hover and simple background colors as shown in above two code in the below code.

```html
<header>
  <nav role='navigation'>
    <ul>
      <li><a  href="#"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"></a></li>
       <li><a  href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a  href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>  
</header>
```

Comment: Post an example of the code you are attempting to write so that we can troubleshoot.

Comment: please give me both html and css format

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service for you, you have to at least attempt to code something and then can get answers to help you fix your problems with that

Comment: ok i will write code

Answer (score 1):

You should create different css class, and add them to your different li elements.

css :

```
.red {background-color: rgb(240,0,0);color: white;}
.red:hover {background-color: rgb(255,0,0);}
.green {background-color: rgb(0,240,0);color: black;}
.green:hover {background-color: rgb(0,255,0);}
```

html :

```
<ul>
<li class="red">bloc with red bg</li>
<li class="red">bloc with red bg</li>
<li class="green">bloc with green bg</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you know any free website to learn programming like JavaScript ,css, HTML,php and ready for a web development